# How can I pass Tab Target to Pop up window E-learning quiz?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-captivate

I am working on the Accessibility standards for a Captivate 9 Generated quiz, this particular quiz opens in a new window when button is clicked, and I need a way for the focus to be passed to that popup window on button click.

Is there a means to do this programmatically with JQuery or javascript?

Edit:

Due to having very little access to the generator that outputs the HTML5 information, I am attempting to pass focus on button click, if this is more feasible.

Comment: is the popup generating a window object for your parent page to consume? Then you could do a window.focus() on the child's window object.

Comment: @Vinny I will try this out now, I was going to attempt to target the inner text of the header, since this quiz always starts with a video.